# matlab inverse turn off pivoting

Tags: matlab, matrix, pivot, sparse-matrix

Is there a way to turn off pivoting when computing the inverse of a tridiagonal matrix in matlab? I'm trying to see if a problem I'm having with solving a tridiagonal system is coming from not pivoting and I can test it simply in matlab by solving the same system and turning off pivoting. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: A cursory glance over the documentation doesn't reveal anything. However, if you're using [`mldivide`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html) to solve your system, MATLAB is using its [Hessenberg solver](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html#bt42oms) and may not be doing pivoting anyway.  You could try comparing your results against a direct [tridiagonal solver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix_algorithm).

Comment: @TroyHaskin: I suggest you change your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation to [`mldivide`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html) doesn't list any options for setting low-level options like that.
I'd imagine that is because automatic pivoting is not only desired but expected from most tools these days.

For a tridiagonal matrix that is full, MATLAB will use its Hessenberg solver (which I imagine is akin to [this flow](https://books.google.com/books?id=vBW5IEEEQBIC&pg=PA197&dq=%22Matrix+Algorithms%22+%22upper+hessenberg+matrix:+say%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FcL1VJ7RLYKLyATwroGIDQ&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22Matrix%20Algorithms%22%20%22upper%20hessenberg%20matrix%3A%20say%22&f=false)) and, for a sparse tridiagonal matrix, will use a [tridiagonal solver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix_algorithm).  In both cases, partial pivoting may used to ensure an accurate solution of the system.

To get around the fact that MATLAB doesn't have a toggle for pivoting, you could implement your own tridiagonal solver (see above link) without pivoting and see how the solution is affected.